# What is few English translations for 吃窩邊草?

Tags: translation

What is few English translations for 吃窩邊草?

I cannot think of one formal or casual translation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like 兔子不吃窝边草?

If so, you could try something like "Don't bite the hand that feeds you" or "Don't foul your own nest."

Colloquially (and if you want a phrase with more profanity) "Don't shit where you eat" is common and could be used instead.

Also, a proverb like "People in glass houses shouldn't throw stones" is pretty intuitive as well.

Comment: 兔子不吃窝边草 being a proverb( 谚语) web supplies many translations

Answer (score 1):

百度 has 兔子不吃窝边草 which they translate as 'A villain doesn't harm his neighbours.' Not sure quite what that means.

I think in a love/sex aspect, it may mean, 'You should not have an affair with your neighbour, or you will be discovered.'